# Python: Convert multiple instances of the same key into multiple rows

Tags: python

I am trying to process a file that looks more or less like this:

```
f=0412345678 t=0523456789 t=0301234567 s=Party! flag=urgent flag=english id=1221AB12
```

I know I can for example use Python shlex to parse those without major issues with something like:

```
entry = "f=0412345678 t=0523456789 t=0301234567 s=Party! flag=urgent flag=english id=1221AB12"

line = shlex.split(entry)
```

I can then do a for loop and iterate over the key value pairs.

```
row = {}
for kvpairs in line:
    key, value = kvpairs.split("=")
    row.setdefault(key,[]).append(value)
print row
```

Results in:

```
{'id': ['1221AB12'], 's': ['Party!'], 'flag': ['urgent', 'english'], 't': ['0523456789', '0301234567'], 'f': ['0412345678']}
```

So far so good but I am having trouble finding an efficient way of outputting the original line so that the output looks like:

```
id=1221AB12 f=0412345678 t=0523456789 s=Party! flag=urgent 
id=1221AB12 f=0412345678 t=0523456789 s=Party! flag=english
id=1221AB12 f=0412345678 t=0301234567 s=Party! flag=urgent 
id=1221AB12 f=0412345678 t=0301234567 s=Party! flag=english
```

Comment: does the order of these key-value pairs matter?

Comment: @SebastianPhilipp: yes. They should print in the same order always. (as the result is more like a TSV than a space separated value as illustrated)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

product from itertools and

```
from itertools import product
from collections import OrderedDict
a = OrderedDict({'id': ['1221AB12'], 's': ['Party!'], 'flag': ['urgent', 'english'], 't': ['0523456789', '0301234567'], 'f':              ['0412345678']})
res = product(*a.values())
for line in res:
    print " ".join(["%s=%s" % (m, n) for m,n in zip(a.keys(), line) ])
```

result

```
s=Party! f=0412345678 flag=urgent id=1221AB12 t=0523456789
s=Party! f=0412345678 flag=urgent id=1221AB12 t=0301234567
s=Party! f=0412345678 flag=english id=1221AB12 t=0523456789
s=Party! f=0412345678 flag=english id=1221AB12 t=0301234567
```

Comment: epic! Mind explaining what is the function of * in front of a? Never seen it before

Comment: for star:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/4768939 (it used to unpack argument list)

Comment: True! I did see it before around args and kwargs... aka... how to spot a terrible coder like me. :-)

Comment: Something like this:

for v in vrows:
    for k in krows:
        print("%s=%s" % (str(k[0]), v[krows.index(k)])),
    print ""

?